# Удалить все нули в конце массива после сортировки

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Сам массив отсортировать получилось, но не пойму как удалить все нули и вывести

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Quest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {5, 4, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 25, 0, 8, 7, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 4};

        System.out.println("Дан массив: " + Arrays.toString((numbers)));
        int temp;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if ((numbers[i] != 0)) {
                temp = numbers[count];
                numbers[count] = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = temp;
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Отсортированный массив с 0 в конце: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

        int[] newNumbers = new int[numbers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
            if ((numbers[i] == 0)) {
                newNumbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
                System.out.println("Отсортированный массив без 0 в конце: " + Arrays.toString(newNumbers[i]));
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Примитивно вторую часть можно так написать:

```
System.out.println("Отсортированный массив с 0 в конце: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

int i;
for ( i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
numbers = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, i);

System.out.println("Отсортированный массив без 0 в конце: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Answer (score 1):

C помощью стримов, например:

```
Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .boxed() // пакуем примитивы в объекты
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()) // сортируем в обратном порядке
    .filter(i -> i != 0) // убираем всё что не равно 0
    .forEach(System.out::println); // выводим
```

Comment: Эффективней сначала отфильтровать, потом сортировать.

Comment: по производительности на 20-ти целых числах разницу невзможно будет заметить - сам запуск jvm займёт в сотни раз больше времени и ресурсов. К тому же, делал в том же порядке, что и автор вопроса, чтобы сохранить ясность.

Comment: Можно и не делать сортировку, а сразу в `TreeMap` запихивать, будет работать быстрее и кода меньше. К тому же `Stream.of` будет предпочтительнее, чем `Arrays.stream`.

Answer (score 0):

На стримах кода значительно меньше получается:

```java
int[] numbers = {5, 4, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 25, 0, 8, 7, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 4};

int[] sorted = Arrays.stream(numbers)
        // без нулей
        .filter(num -> num != 0)
        // без повторов
        .distinct()
        // сортировка в обратном порядке
        .boxed().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        // возвращаем массив
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted)); // [25, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: `distinct` можно убрать, если не нужно.